# A problem from the chapter 'theory of equations'

Tags: linear-algebra

Question : Form a biquadratic equation with rational coefficients two of whose roots are √3 + 2 and √3 - 2.

So f(x) = (x- √3-2)(x-√3+2)q(x) where q(x) must be a quadratic equation. This is how far I have done. But I cannot solve it. I am a Bsc student with maths as an ancillary paper. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*. Have a look at $(\sqrt 3 + 2)(\sqrt 3 - 2)$ and $(\sqrt 3 + 2) - (\sqrt 3 - 2)$, and try using “Vieta’s formula” (it’s the distributive law, really), saying $(X - α)(X - β) = X^2 - (α+β)X + αβ$.

Answer (score 0):

Write a quadratic equation which has roots $x_1=\left(\sqrt{3}+2\right)^2=7+4 \sqrt{3};\;x_2=\left(\sqrt{3}-2\right)^2=7-4 \sqrt{3}$

We need the sum and the product of the roots
$x_1+x_2=14;\;x_1x_2=\left(7+4 \sqrt{3}\right)\left(7-4 \sqrt{3}\right)=1$

$$(x-x_1)(x-x_2)=x^2-(x_1+x_2)x+x_1x_2=x^2-14x+1$$
And then substitute $x$ with $x^2$
$$x^4-14x^2+1=0$$

Comment: Wow..thanks for the help. It matches with the answer given